# How do I send user information over KryoNet?

Tags: java, networking, kryonet

I've created a gameserver containing an ArrayList of players (Player). However, as far as i've been able to read, Kryonet can't send objects with a constructor in it to the client (Player have that), so i need to find an alternate way of transferring the ArrayList.

What would be a proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JMS implementation (in my case it ActiveMq) and send a Object message.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the object have a default constructor with no arguments. you can still create the object with a constructor that takes in parameters.

Comment: I would not use ActiveMQ unless the current release is much better than version 5.0 which I found to be very buggy.